# find files and move them to another folder with -exec

Tags: find, mv

I tried to find files and move them to another folder

```
$ find ~ -iregex ".*cheat.*\.pdf" -exec mv "{}" cheatSheet +
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

However, the test works

```
find ~ -iregex ".*cheat.*\.pdf" -exec echo {} +
```

What's the problem with my usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `-exec ... {} +`, the `{}` must be at the end, just before the `+`.

This means that you would have to use

```
-exec mv -t cheatSheet {} +
```

which would require access to GNU `mv`.  Without GNU `mv`, you would use

```
-exec mv {} cheatSheat \;
```

to move one file at a time, or

```
-exec sh -c 'mv "$@" cheatSheet' sh {} +
```

to call an in-line script that moves all files in one go.

You additionally don't need `-iregex`.  The following will be easier to read and understand:

```
find "$HOME" -ipath '*cheat*.pdf' \
    -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" cheatSheet' sh {} +
```

or, for clarity, either one of the following which does what you actually mean (it depends on whether you want `cheat` to be part of the *filename* at the end of the path (the first alternative), or one of the *directory names* in the path (the second alternative)):

```
find "$HOME" -iname '*cheat*.pdf' \
    -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" cheatSheet' sh {} +

find "$HOME" -ipath '*cheat*/*' -iname '*.pdf' \
    -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" cheatSheet' sh {} +
```

Note that `-ipath` is a GNU `find` extension, but that `-iname`, though non-standard, is more commonly implemented.

Also worth noting is that if you have name collisions, i.e. files with exactly the same name, you will overwrite some already moved files in the process of moving other files.  With GNU `mv`, you may avoid this by using either the `-n` option (will not clobber existing files) or the `-b` option (rename/backup existing files).

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Answer (score 1):

The `{}` needs to be a the end of the `-exec` command.  The `mv` command supports this with the `-t` option:

```
mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
```

So your command would be:

```
find ~ -iregex ".*cheat.*\.pdf" -exec mv -t cheatSheet "{}" +
```